# Problems with JavaScript for multi-upload

Tags: c#, javascript, html, multi-upload

I'm trying to make a multi-file upload. with help from this [blog](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/azamsharp/archive/2007/10/25/Upload-Multiple-Files-Using-WebClient.UploadFile-Method.aspx), but is getting an error.

the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Upload_Multiple_Files._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var selectedFiles = '';

        function ReceiveServerData(response) {
            alert(response);
        }

        function uploadFile() {
            var fileList = document.getElementById("fileDivBox").getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

            for (i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                selectedFiles += fileList[i].value + "|";
            }

            CallServer(selectedFiles, '');
        }

        function attachFile() {
            var fu = document.createElement("INPUT");

            fu.type = "file";

            var br = document.createElement("<BR>");

            document.getElementById("fileDivBox").appendChild(fu);
            document.getElementById("fileDivBox").appendChild(br);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <a href="#" onclick="attachFile()">Attach a file</a> 
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

codebehind:

```
namespace Upload_Multiple_Files
{
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        string[] files = (eventArgument.TrimEnd('|')).Split('|');

        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            client.UploadFile("http://localhost:3850/FileServer.aspx", "POST", file);
        } 
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\UploadedFiles\"; // server folder

        string[] keys = Request.Files.AllKeys;

        foreach (String key in keys)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[key];

            file.SaveAs(path + file.FileName);
        }
    }
}
}
```

the error occours in the line: `br = document.createElement("<BR>");`
where it says "unhandled exeption". I'm new to javascript thereby having no clue was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document.CreateElement function will add the < > part of the tag for you. What your code is attempting to do is create an element of `<<br>>`, which is invalid. Call the method with just the tag name of BR:

```
br = document.CreateElement("BR");
```

This will create a `<br>` tag for you as you expect.